# Is there a way to install the QuickTime plugin for Firefox without the bloatware from Apple?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, plugins, quicktime

I remember using QuickTime Lite. However QT Lite was last updated on 18 Dec 2010 and uses QuickTime base components [version 7.69.80.9]. Current QuickTime according to apple.com is QuickTime 7.7.2.

So it's outdated!

Any way I can install QuickTime 7.7.2 for the plugin for Firefox without all the useless bloatware from apple.com?

Comment: The version difference between 7.69.8 and 7.7.2 is minor. Take a look at the changelogs for [7.7](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4826), [7.7.1](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5016), and [7.7.2](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5261) - it seems that it's been mostly security fixes but given the small version increments, the vulnerabilities are rare. So as long as you don't use QT on some sketchy sites, you should be fine.

Comment: Doesn't matter to me. I like my plugins to be up-to-date. So no, I won't use QT Lite 4.1.0.

Comment: In that case, this question will stay open until the new version comes out. There's really no other alternative to QT Lite.

Answer (score 1):

Just because the last QT Lite version is a few steps behind than the latest full release, it doesn't mean that the software is obsolete. Just [download it from FileHippo](http://www.filehippo.com/download_quicktime_alternative/) to be safe.

Comment: Which is QT lite, what I was talking about in my original post.

Comment: Ouch. Weird. How did I not read that? o_O

Comment: I didn't say it's obsolete. I'm just looking for an up-to-date Quicktime plugin for Firefox without all the useless bloatware.